# How to append a list of zeros onto 'NoneType' list?

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to append a list of zeros of specified length onto a list containing strings and class objects. I have tried:

```
data = []

for i in range(0,numData):
   data.append([object1, parentName[i], object2, className[i], [0]*len(variableOutputList)])
```

But this gives me an list with shape(1,5):

```
[[<object at 0xxxxx8>, 'str', <object at 0xxxxx8>, 'str', [0, 0, 0]]
```

The output that I would like to get is an list with shape(1,7) (in this case, obviously would be different with different len(variableOutputList)):

```
[<object at 0xxxxx8>, 'str', <object at 0xxxxx8>, 'str', 0, 0, 0]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: can you post the valid expected output. the list you posted is incomplete

Comment: There are no arrays involved here. You have a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this to

```
for i in range(0,numData):
   data.append([object1, parentName[i], object2, className[i], [0]*len(variableOutputList)])
```

this

```
for i in range(0,numData):
   data.append([object1, parentName[i], object2, className[i]] + [0]*len(variableOutputList))
```

Answer (score 1):

The list you are appending to `data` contains the list `[0, 0, 0]`, not the seperate elements `0`, `0`, and `0`.

```
data.append([object1, parentName[i], object2, className[i]] + [0]*len(variableOutputList)])
```

or

```
data.append([object1, parentName[i], object2, className[i], *[0]*len(variableOutputList)])
```

---

I would be partial to a few extra lines of code for clarity:

```
new_item = [object1, parentName[i], object2, className[i]]
new_item.extend(0 for _ in variableOutputList)
data.append(new_item)
```